# How do I raise the Assassin's influence in cities over 50%?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

It seems to be capped at 50% for me. Is this normal, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more assassins you have stationed in a city, and the higher their level, the higher your maximum influence in that city is.  If you enter the assassin management interface, you can see it listed as current%/maximum%.  Three or four high-level assassins is enough to get it close to max.  (There's really no reason not to fill them up with your low-level assassins constantly - a fully upgraded city will send them all to level 6 or 7 in a day).

Comment: I never noticed that you could send assassins to the cities. Doh! Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, you can use the assassins stationed at those cities to do missions there.  You'll need a minimum of 2 to be able to do so since you always need one free assassin on watch.